# Please help me to make use of for XML (' ') in the below case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

one column contains ID and for same ID their are different names.

```
ID     Name
1     Amrutha
1     Ankith
1     Lalitha
1     Kavitha
2     Nithin
2     Raghu
2     Pramodh
```

The result should be

```
1   Amrutha,Ankitha,Lalitha,Kavitha
2   Nithin,Raghu,Pramodh
```

Please Help me doing this.I am getting error when i made use of Group by clause.

Comment: do you want to do this with just sql or  in combination with a programming language ?

Comment: @Prashant : SQL. Colud you please help me doing this?

Comment: Can any one help me with the above Please

Comment: I have found a answer for myself... :-)

Comment: select id,stuff((Select ','+t.name from t where t.id = b.id for xml path ('')),1,1,'')as dept from t b group by id

Comment: @Pearl - please add your answer as the "answer" to this question so others will be able to find it without digging through the comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  id,
  stuff(
   ( Select ','+t.name from t where t.id = b.id for xml path ('') ),
   1, 1, ''
  ) as dept
from t b
group by id
```